# Why does this return an empty array?

Tags: perl

Why does this return an empty list despite giving `$sub=1000`. What is the purpose of "$#" in ARGV?

```
use strict;
my $sub = 0;
while($sub <= $#ARGV) {
print "$ARGV[$sub]\n";
++$sub;
}
print "[@ARGV]\n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$#array` notation gives you the index of the last element in `@array`.

`@ARGV` contains the command line arguments to your program. If you didn't supply any arguments when running your program, that list will be empty.

So it goes into the `while`, where `$sub` is `0`, which is larger than `-1`. So it never goes into the loop.

Hence, this program should output only a line with empty `[]`.

```
$ perl foo.pl
[]
$
```

See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40ARGV) for more details on `@ARGV` and [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Variable-names) for `$#array`.

Comment: I was wrong about the empty line. Corrected.

Comment: thank you @simbabque ps:tried upvoting but couldn't

Comment: Note: even if `@ARGV` is not defined, `$#ARGV` is not `undef`, it is -1

Comment: @GRD you can accept after a bit more time has passed. You can only upvote after you have 15 yourself. See the [faq] for that. :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland thank you, fixed. That's very hidden. perldata says it only when talking about that you can assign `$#foo = -1` which is the same as `@foo = ()`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland@simbabque: ok I really have to ask! why is $#foo=-1? thanks

Comment: @GRD I was loosely quoting from perldata. The only reference to the fact that `$#foo` will be `-1` when `@foo` is the empty list `()` is this: it says these two statements are equal: `@foo = ()` and `$#foo = -1`. Check http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values and ctrl+f search for `-1;`

Comment: @GRD, `$#foo` is 0 when `@foo` has 1 element (because Perl arrays are indexed from 0).  An empty array has 1 less element, so `$#foo` is -1.